# First time buyers in the UK

Tags: mortgage, united-kingdom, first-time-home-buyer

Are there currently any grants or interest free loans available to first time buyers in the north of England on a home worth around £145,000?

My partner and I are looking to purchase a house in the north of England worth around £145,000. We have a sizable deposit, but the monthly payments are higher than we wanted due to interest.

Are there any grants or low/no-tax loans available?

Comment: Check here https://www.gov.uk/affordable-home-ownership-schemes/overview. And how much deposit do you have ? With a higher deposit you can get a very low rate of interest. For a 60% LTV you can probably get a rate of 1.2% and maybe even lower. Try shopping around.

Comment: Not what you asked, but if the monthly payments are too high right now while we have such a historically low interest rate, then you should be seriously questioning whether you can afford the house at all. As a very rough rule of thumb, for every point the interest rates go up, and for every £100k borrowed, you will pay an extra £100 / month. Make sure you can afford whatever deal you end up with even if interest rates go up to 6, 7 or 8%.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The payments aren't out of our reach by any means but we are making sure that we can still afford the home even if one of us were to lose our how.

Comment: The real question is if you can afford the payment plus £300 (if rates rise 2.5%, not beyond the realms of possibility in the next few years) on one income. You could potentially look at a joint ownership scheme or the help to buy schemes